# number leaving different remainders with different divisors

Tags: education

number when divided by 17 leaves remainder 3 and when divided by 16 leaves remainder 10 and is divisible by 15

find the smallest number in the series

i tried the conventional method but it gave me wrong answer 
so please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the number is $x=3930$, which is unique modulo $4080$.

Comment: the no is divisible by all the numbers i.e 15,16,17
but i need a number which leaves a remainder 3 and 10 when divided by 17,16 respectively

Comment: $3930=15\cdot 262+0=16\cdot 245+10=17\cdot 231+3$, so why are you not satisfied ?